# First entry not easy to click issue in firefox,a bug?

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-float

Pay attention to the part in blue in the first table.

Can check out the problem [here](http://51hired.com)

[alt text http://51hired.com/static/problem.gif](http://51hired.com/static/problem.gif)

**EDIT**
reproduce by double click at the upper part of first entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the invisible text and "View Selection Source" in FireFox you'll get the following source:

```
<div class="sub_i_title">
  <a href="/questions/" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;">更多»»</a>
  <h2 style="line-height: 1em; display: block;">最新的问题</h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

Could it be that your source has bad whitespace? I estimate that the problem is the following line:

```
"<h2>最新的问题</h2>                                                         "
```

If you Select All on the page, you'll find that under each H2 there is the same amount of white space, and it seems to be covering the first link in each list.

In fact, if you save your page and open it in an editor where you can see the ASCII/HEX values for each character, you'll find that the offending whitespace characters are actually `A0` in HEX, but a normal space is `20`. Could it be that you have an IME activated and a bad whitespace character was inserted?

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing similar bug reports in bugzilla.mozilla.org, but in order to find out anything definitive about this, you'll need to create a [simple testcase](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Reducing_testcases).

Then it's possible to tell if it's a bug and try to find its current status.

Or you could try searching bugzilla.m.o for similar issues; it'll be hard to tell if the problem you found is the same as yours or simply has similar effects.

Answer (score 0):

The line-height of the h2 above it is too high, it's overlapping. I'd say set z-indexes to fix it or change the h2 line-height.

More reading here: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: tested in FF on mac with firebug and changing line-height fixed it. z-indexes not tested but should do the trick as well

Comment: Tried you solution,but not working.In fact it's really odd that if I save it as a static html file,the problem is gone.